# How do you work out the segmentation table, offset and frame size in segmented memory management?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, memory-allocation

If I had a process, 1, which has the following segments:

Segment 1 - 50 bytes

Segment 2 - 200 bytes

Segment 3 - 90 bytes

and I know that the total bytes in memory is 1024, how do I work out the offset/base/limit and the frame size for each segment that needs to be placed in physical memory?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Finding a *frame* size should get interesting. Start by suggesting a size for the smallest accessible unit of memory (*word*).

Comment: There seems to be some information missing here. Are there any constraints on how the segments are arranged in physical memory?